# Powershell: Why are my RegKey value checks failing using Get-ItemProperty when the value I am checking for is 0?

Tags: windows, powershell, object, registry

I have been tasked with scripting regkey checks to make sure a sampling of machines are compliant with our security posture.

The script works great when checking for any non-zero value (such as the example input below).
however, there is a consistent theme where my code if erroneously reporting that the checks have failed if the desired value is 0. See example code below:

```
$failReview = "" #String to track compliance issues
$OutFile = "C:\local\file.text"


Function Test-STIG_SingleKey {
  
    #check for single acceptable key value
    #up to 3 additional acceptable key values may be checked for single key

    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string[]] $CV,     #Check Vulnerability number
        [string[]] $Path,   #RegKey Path
        [string[]] $Key,    #Key to check
        [int] $value,       #Expected Regkey value for compliance
        $FailReview,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [int] $value1,      #optional acceptable value
        [int] $value2,      #optional acceptable value
        [int] $value3       #optional acceptable value
    )
    Begin {}

    Process {
        
        $KeyObject = Get-ItemProperty $Path                                 #Obtain RegKey object values using RegKey Path
        $Exist = ([bool]($KeyObject.PSObject.Properties.name -imatch $Key)) #Check for match of key value property name and cast to boolean
        If(!($Exist)){                                                                                      #If does NOT exist
            Write-Host "    !!! $CV is a finding !!!" -ForegroundColor "Red"; $Global:failReview += "$CV, "} #This IS a finding, append CV to list for review
        ElseIf (($KeyObject)."$Key" = $value){                              #checks relevant object property value and compares to Primary expected value
            Write-Host "    $CV is not a finding" -ForegroundColor "Green"
        } 
        ElseIf (((($KeyObject)."$Key" = $value1) -or (($KeyObject)."$Key" = $value2) -or (($KeyObject)."$Key" = $value3))) { #alternate acceptable value check
            Write-Host "    $CV is not a finding, alternate acceptable values used" -ForegroundColor "Green"    #not a finding, but indicates alt value present
        }
        else {Write-Host "    !!! $CV is a finding !!!" -ForegroundColor "Red"; $Global:FailReview += "$CV, "} #This IS a finding, append CV to list for review                                              

    }
    End {Return $CV, $Path, $Key, $value, $KeyObject, $failReview | Out-File $OutFile -Append}         #Pass all variable values to out-file for review if needed
}


#EXAMPLE INPUT:
Test-STIG_SingleKey -CV "V70955" `
-Path "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_HTTP_USERNAME_PASSWORD_DISABLE" `
-Key "excel.exe" `
-value 1
```

I can obtain the value manually by looking at $KeyObject.Key, but can't seem to get the output to evaluate to true if I'm looking for a 0.

I think this is likely because it's evaluating the 0 to $false at some point, but it's an int.
I've already tried casting to [int] and converting it to hex.

Any advice would be appreciated, because I've almost spent more time trying to figure this out then it would take to just manually look at the keys for the sampling that we require.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because in your `if` statements, you are setting `($KeyObject)."$Key"` equal to something instead of checking if it is set to a particular value.

So

```
... ElseIf (($KeyObject)."$Key" = $value){ ...
```

should be

```
... ElseIf (($KeyObject)."$Key" -eq $value){ ...
```